# Duplicate onClick events on LI element in iScroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll4

Here is my code.. When I am calling this function, iScroll() added duplicate events on LI element after change page.

```
function collectionOffen(asseID, imgsInFile) {
  $("#thelist").empty();

  // append image files into slider div.. 
  for (var imgPageCnt = 0; imgPageCnt <= imgsInFile; imgPageCnt++) {
      var html = "";
      html += "<li id=" + imgPageCnt + ">";
      html += "<img src='" + preThmb + "'>";
      html += "</li>";

      $("#thelist").append(html);

      funcPreImg = function () {
          previewImageBackside(asseID);
      }

      document.getElementById(imgPageCnt).addEventListener("click", funcPreImg);
  }

  $("#thelist").listview("refresh");
  $.mobile.changePage("#collectionOfFiles", {
      transition: "slide",
      reverse: true
  });
  var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}
```

Tell me solution if any..

Comment: It's recommended that id starts with a letter rather than a number.

Answer (score 1):

duplicated events are a common problem in jqm.

Try this (untestet braincode):

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
  $("#thelist").empty();

  // append image files into slider div.. 
  for (var imgPageCnt = 0; imgPageCnt <= imgsInFile; imgPageCnt++) {
      var html = "";
      html += "<li id='" + imgPageCnt + "' class='imgClass'>";
      html += "<img src='" + preThmb + "'>";
      html += "</li>";

      $("#thelist").append(html);
  }

  //is 'asseID' defined in this context?
  $(document).on('click', '.imgClass', function (e) {
      if(e.handled !== true)
      {
          previewImageBackside(asseID);
          e.handled = true;
      }
  });

  $("#thelist").listview("refresh");
  $.mobile.changePage("#collectionOfFiles", {
      transition: "slide",
      reverse: true
  });
  var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
});
```

this should add your list elements only on initialization of the page.

also changed your javascript function into a nicer and performant jquerycall.

you also had a typo in `"<li id='" + imgPageCnt + "'>"`, missing quotes

Comment: when you comment iScroll(),then code works fine. iScroll added duplicates events.

Comment: updated my example, if the event is handled it won't be executed twice

Comment: it's not a working solution, i said that before - it should push you in the right direction. 

if iscroll is messing around with your events, maybe you should take a look at the iscroll documentation and understand its inner behaviour.

Comment: Usually clicks taps or vclick may be triggered multiple times when having a multipage template and you're changing from one page to the next and then back again (visiting a page the second, third 4th time). Events are triggered (every time) you're revisiting the page when binding to events e.g. on pageshow. To avoid this bind as follows: `$(document).off('click', '.imgClass').on('click', '.imgClass', function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Destroy iScroll object after rendering images.

Ex:-
       var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
       myScroll.refresh();
       myScroll.destroy();

take myScroll as static variable to  destroy object.